# Not able to send an ArrayList in a POST request to the REST server using Java

Tags: java, rest

I am a newbie to the Java REST services, rather this whole Java client-server thing. I'm trying to implement the basic client server design.

From client side I am trying to POST an `ArrayList` of objects of a particular class (POJO). Following is my client side code:

```
public class TestClient1 {

    private static final String webServiceURI = "http://localhost:8080/IadssitHPCServer";
    private static URI serviceURI;
    private static WebTarget webTarget;
    private static ArrayList<ImageInput> imageList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        Client client   = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
        serviceURI  = UriBuilder.fromUri(webServiceURI).build();
        webTarget   = client.target(serviceURI);
        webTarget   = webTarget.path("clientserver").path("restservice").path("analyze");

        imageList = new ArrayList<ImageInput>();

        /*
          Code to add objects in the Arraylist
        */  

        Session session= webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
                post(Entity.entity(imageList, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML), Session .class);
    }
}
```

`ImageInput` (POJO) class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ImageInput implements Serializable {

    private String imageName;
    private String imageDirPath;

    public String getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }
    public void setImageName(String imageName) {
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }
    public String getImageDirPath() {
        return imageDirPath;
    }
    public void setImageDirPath(String imageDirPath) {
        this.imageDirPath = imageDirPath;
    }
}
```

At server:

```
@Path( "/hpcservice" )
@Consumes( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
public class HpcService {

    @POST
    @Path( "/analyze" )
    public Session startAnalysing(ArrayList<ImageInput> clientInput){
        System.out.println( "Started Analyzing..." );
        return session;
    }
}
```

Server returns the object of the class `Session` which is again a POJO class.

When I execute the code it gives me following error at client side:

```
Oct 19, 2015 3:01:10 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:503)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:435)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:338)
    at com.TestClient1.main(TestClient1.java:61)
```

I think may be I am doing something wrong with the type of request I am sending and receiving. How does this `MediaType.APPLICATION_..` affect/vary with the different data structure I am sending?

I know I am asking a very basic level questions here, but whatever online solutions I find even on Stack Overflow, I am getting more confused.

Comment: use json to represent the contents of arraylist

Comment: REST API uses String for communication ... you should represent your objects in String representation

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I have added code of ImageInput class. My arraylist contents are the object of this class. How do I represent these objects using json? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I also advice you learn more about json which will be helpful in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using a wrapper class

Consider wrapping your `ArrayList<ImageInput>` into a class, like the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ImageInputData {

    @XmlElement
    private ArrayList<ImageInput> images;

    // Getters and setters ommited
}
```

Your endpoint method will look like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/analyze")
public Session startAnalysing(ImageInputData inputData) {

    List<ImageInput> images = inputData.getImages();    
    // Do any processing...
    return session;
}
```

### Using JSON

Alternatively, you can consume JSON instead of XML. To do it, remove the following annotation from your enpoints:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
```

And add the following:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

If you would like to support both XML and JSON representations, use:

```
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
```

**MOXy**

As you are using JAXB annotations, it's interesting highlight that you can use JAXB annotations to generate JSON with Jersey.

To do so, you will need to add the MOXy dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven make sure to have all needed dependencies described in this [link](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-moxy/dependencies.html) on your classpath.

**Jackson 2.x**

Jackson 2.x provides a [very rich set of annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) to generate JSON from POJOS.

If you prefer using Jackson 2.x as your JSON provider you need the following dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven, make sure you have all the dependencies described in this [link](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html) on your classpath.

### More information

To know more about the support for common media type representations have a look at this [link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html).

Comment: Using the wrapper class is the optimal solution in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to convert the arraylist to JSON before sending it to server. The same can be done using gson jar.

```
DataObject obj = new DataObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();

// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Send this string to the server. At server parse json representation to construct your Object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//convert the json string back to object
DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);
```

`DataObject` in your case will be `ArrayList`.

Have a look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 1):

They JAXB (default java xml parser), does not know how to handle ArrayList as a given obect (since it is anonymous etc'). try using a wrapper class that has an ArrayList as a field, then sending that class instead of sending the Arraylist directly